# Moving the last character in a cell to the beginning of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am reconciling some information in Excel sheet that a coworker forwarded to me, but some information with the date and time-stamp was copied in wrong. Somehow, the first character of some cells in a column ended up at the end of the cell to the left. My question is, what rule could I write to select the last character of a cell, and add it to the beginning of another cell?

Here is a snip of the issue:

[image: Excel Snip of time-stamp error]

So for example:

Cell A1 currently has "8/9/2016 9" and Cell B1 has ":20:00 AM"

Cell A1 needs to be "8/9/2016" and Cell B1 needs to be "9:20:00 AM"

Comment: To do it in place you will need vba.  If you want to use formulas then it will need to be in different cells.

Comment: Did you import this from a text file or was it given to you this way?

Comment: Also, You have two different senerios with the times and the dates.  for example you have `9/9/2019 1` with the time `2:56 PM` what should it be?

Comment: @CharlieRB it was given to me this way unfortunately.

Comment: @ScottCraner the time stamp for that one should read "12:56 PM"

Comment: Okay I can see that but a little further down you have `9/9/2019 1` with a time of `12:36 AM`, what should that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula answer is this:

For the date:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,--LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

For the Time:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(A1),B1,IF(ISNUMBER(--(RIGHT(A1,1) & TEXT(B1,"H:MM AM/PM"))),--(RIGHT(A1,1) & TEXT(B1,"H:MM AM/PM")),--(RIGHT(A1,1) & B1))),B1)
```

Then Format the cells "Short Date" and "Time" respectively.

[image: ![enter image description here]